# Write a function to shuffle a given list. Make sure that all permutations are equally probable

Tags: lua, shuffle, fisher-yates-shuffle

Whilst reading [Programming in Lua](https://www.lua.org/pil/#4ed) book, I came across an exercise which I'm not sure if I solved right, hence I wanted to ask you all.

Problem statement:

> **Exercise 6.4: Write a function to shuffle a given list. Make sure that all permutations are equally probable.**

Background: I've very basic mathematical and programmings knowledge

I researched a bit online, read a bit about combinations vs permutations, how does that come into play in this problem, and then I finally came across [Fisher-Yates Shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) which I think led me to a "working" solution.

My ask:

- Is my solution right? If not, what am I doing wrong? If yes, perhaps some details entailing why because I'm confused as to how would I be otherwise shuffling the list with **unequal probabilities**?
- One thing I noticed is if I add `math.randomseed(1)` (or, any other fixed number) in the `getShuffledList` function, I always get the same results, no matter how many times I try to shuffle the list. Why does that happen?

My solution:

```lua
local printList = function (a)
  for _, value in ipairs(a) do
    io.write(value, " ")
  end
  print()
end

local interchangeElements = function(list, i , j)
  local temp
  temp = list[i]
  list[i] = list[j]
  list[j] = temp
  return list
end

local getShuffledList = function(list)
  -- math.randomseed(1) --> gives constant shuffled list on each call
  local j
  for i = #list, 1, -1 do
    j = math.random(1, #list)
    interchangeElements(list, i, j)
  end
  return list
end

printList(getShuffledList({1, 2, 3, 4}))
printList(getShuffledList({1, 2, 3, 4}))
printList(getShuffledList({1, 2, 3, 4}))
printList(getShuffledList({1, 2, 3, 4}))
```

Output:

```bash
3 2 4 1 
3 4 2 1 
4 3 1 2 
1 2 3 4 

[Process exited 0]
```

Comment: Some notes on your code: (1) You can use `local function f(...)` as a shorthand for `local f; f = function(...)` (this is esp. convenient for recursive functions, but it's also fine to use it for non-recursive ones); (2) Swapping two elements is just `list[i], list[j] = list[j], list[i]` in Lua (multiple assignments copy), no need to introduce a helper function for that; (3) `printList` could be implemented more succintly as `print(table.concat(list, " "))`. For quick'n'dirty debugging, `print(table.unpack(list))` also works.

Comment: As for "is my solution right?": The nice thing about code is that you can easily test it. Randomized algorithms are harder to test, but you can still run some basic tests - for example, if you just count how often each number appears in each position, or average the numbers for each position, you should roughly get an equal distribution. [I happen to have such a test lying around](https://github.com/TheAlgorithms/Lua/blob/main/.spec/random/shuffle_spec.lua). Your implementation will likely fail this test due to reasons outlined by tehtmi.

Comment: Thanks @Luatic Sweet tricks you've got up your hand, surely implemented them. Question on testing the code (post-fix), I see the code in GitHub link provided by you shuffles the array 1e5 times but I don't get how you're asserting the results by comparing difference of max and min sum being lesser than 1e4? Why 1e4 and how does this prove? Again, apologies for lack of my knowledge in the topic

Comment: Thanks @tehtmi I understand the gaps now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is my solution right?

This is not a correct Fisher-Yates shuffle, and the results are not equally probable. This is not obvious, but easy to show with some well-known math.

Let's call the length of the list `n`. In each iteration of your loop, you choose a number between `1` and `n`. There are `n` iterations, so there are `n^n` equally likely ways that all the numbers can be chosen. The number of permutations of the list is `n` factorial. (Except in trivial small cases), there is no way to divide `n` factorial permutations evenly into the `n^n` outcomes, thus it is impossible for all the permutations to be equally likely. For example with `n=4`, there are 24 permutations, but 256 ways the random numbers can be chosen. 24 doesn't divide into 256 evenly, so there is no way to assign an permutation to each of the 256 random outcomes so that they all appear the same number of times.

To get the proper Fisher-Yates algorithm, change `j = math.random(1, #list)` to `j = math.random(1, i)`. This means that the previous counterargument no longer applies: the first random number is from `1` to `n`, then `1` to `n - 1`, etc. So, the number of ways the random numbers can be chosen is also `n` factorial. This doesn't automatically prove that the algorithm works properly; you need to think about it and realize that each permutation can be reached by exactly one way of choosing the random numbers (or you only have to prove that each permutation is possible since the numbers are the same).

> One thing I noticed is if I add `math.randomseed(1)` [...], I always get the same results[...] Why does that happen?

`math.random` is a pseudo-random number generator. This means that it has some hidden internal state, and each time you call it, it does some mysterious but deterministic operation to modify its internal state and return a mysterious number. But, it is not actually random (because common computer operations are inherently always deterministic) (hence "pseudo-random").

`math.randomseed` sets the hidden internal state. Because everything is deterministic, if you start with the same state, you will get the same result. This feature can be useful, e.g. to reproduce the same result later, but it is not useful if you just want "random" numbers.

In Lua 5.4, Lua tries to automatically choose a different starting seed value each time you run the program, so there is not any great need to manually provide a seed when the program starts (but also a no-argument version of `math.randomseed()` is added to allow this behavior to be invoked explicitly). In earlier versions of Lua it is common to do something like `math.randomseed(os.time())` so that you get a different seed each time (well, it will be different if at least a second of real time has passed).